# Can't read my variable outside of my function using Cheerio (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, variables, cheerio

I am new to JavaScript and I am having troubles with my web-scraper program. I followed a tutorial to get cyptocurrencies value out of a website, but for some reasons I can't read the variable "price" outside of my function.
Here's my code

```
const axios = require("axios")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const{ Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const { parse } = require("dotenv");

    async function getPriceFeed() {
        try {
            const siteUrl = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/raptoreum/"

            const {data} = await axios({
                method : "GET",
                url: siteUrl,
            })

            const $ = cheerio.load(data)
            const elemSelector = "#__next > div.bywovg-1.fUzJes > div.main-content > div.sc-57oli2-0.comDeo.cmc-body-wrapper > div > div.sc-16r8icm-0.eMxKgr.container > div.n78udj-0.jskEGI > div > div.sc-16r8icm-0.kjciSH.priceSection > div.sc-16r8icm-0.kjciSH.priceTitle > div"

            $(elemSelector).each((parentIdx, parentElem) => {
                    $(parentElem).children().each((childIdx, childElem) =>{
                       var price = $(parentElem).text();
                       return price;
                })
            })
        }catch(err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    };

console.log(price)
```

Thank you for your help,
Vicriya

EDIT :

I tried to declare my variable outside of my function, my program no longer crashes but the console now logs me undefined. It should log the crypto price instead.

```
const axios = require("axios")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const{ Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const { parse } = require("dotenv");
var price;
    async function getPriceFeed() {
        try {
            const siteUrl = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/raptoreum/"

            const {data} = await axios({
                method : "GET",
                url: siteUrl,
            })

            const $ = cheerio.load(data)
            const elemSelector = "#__next > div.bywovg-1.fUzJes > div.main-content > div.sc-57oli2-0.comDeo.cmc-body-wrapper > div > div.sc-16r8icm-0.eMxKgr.container > div.n78udj-0.jskEGI > div > div.sc-16r8icm-0.kjciSH.priceSection > div.sc-16r8icm-0.kjciSH.priceTitle > div"

            $(elemSelector).each((parentIdx, parentElem) => {
                    $(parentElem).children().each((childIdx, childElem) =>{
                       price = $(parentElem).text();
                       return price;
                })
            })
        }catch(err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    };

console.log(price)
```

Comment: If you put `var price` inside of a function, it can't be read outside of that function. You could solve it by declaring `var price` outside of all functions and then setting it later using only `price = ..`.

Comment: When I do this, the console logs me "undefined", but my program no longer crash when I run it. However it should log me the price of the currency.

Comment: That depends on when you log it. It will only hold the price after your `await` has returned.

Comment: Do you invoke `getPriceFeed()` anywhere? You'll need to invoke the function prior logging `price` on console.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that should get the data you're after:

```js
const axios = require("axios")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")

const getPriceFeed = async () => {
  const siteUrl = "<your URL>";
  const {data} = await axios.get(siteUrl);
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);
  return $(".priceValue").text();
};

getPriceFeed().then(console.log); // => $0.0016890.0079
```

Once you go async, which is necessary for all network requests, you can no longer populate a synchronous variable. You have to `await` or `.then` all promises leading to any further uses of the result of the async code.

Try to be less specific with your CSS selector. Choose a class and/or id or two, enough to disambiguate the element, then stop. A huge tree is liable to break if the site changes at all and isn't pretty to read.

`.each` doesn't seem relevant since there's only one piece of data you appear to want, if I'm not mistaken. If you are working with an array, the `return` needs to happen at the end of the async function, after the loop is done. Return values from `.each` functions are ignored--they don't break out of the nested functions and pop control back to the original caller or anything like that.

See also: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)